# Is it possible to convert Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<T> to Concurrency::task<T>?

Tags: c++-winrt

As in the question, is it possible to convert between Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation  and Concurrency::task?

If so, how to do it?

Update 1.

I'm migrating from C++/CX to C++/winrt and I have the following constructor in C++/CX code:

```
XamlComponentConstructor:XamlComponentConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Uri^ uri = ref new Uri(L"URI");
    create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri))
    .then([this](StorageFile^ file) 
    {
        return Windows::Storage::FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file);
    })
    .then([this](Platform::String^ text) 
    {
        // Text processing 

        x_firstTextBox->Text = var1;
        x_secondTextBox->Text = var2;
    })
}
```

The main problem is that there is no possibility to use corutines in the class constructor.
So the following code doesn't work:

```
XamlComponentConstructor:XamlComponentConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    const auto uri = winrt::Uri(L"URI");
    const auto file { co_await StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri) };
    const auto text { co_await winrt::FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file) };

    //Text processing

    x_firstTextBox->Text = var1;
    x_secondTextBox->Text = var2;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to change this code to work?

Comment: Possibly, I don't know. But what is the concrete problem you are trying to solve? Last time I thought I'd need to use the ConcRT (and it's `task` template), I simply didn't understand coroutines well enough to produce a solution in other ways.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot `co_await` an awaitable in a c'tor. But that's not what the C++/CX does either. It merely fires off an asynchronous task with continuations, without `await`-ing the result. An equivalent C++/WinRT implementations could simply call a function that returns a [fire_and_forget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/fire-and-forget) struct from the c'tor.

Answer (score 0):

you can call do like following code.

```
XamlComponentConstructor:XamlComponentConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    const auto uri = winrt::Uri(L"URI");
    StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).Completed(
        [this](auto const& res, AsyncStatus const status)
        {
            StorageFile file {  res.GetResults() };
            winrt::FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file).Completed[this](
                auto const& res, AsyncStatus const status)
                {
                    auto text = res.GetResults();
                    //your code
                }
        }
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Capturing `[this]` is brittle. If the completion continuations run after the object has been destroyed, all hell breaks loose. [Strong and weak references in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references) provides solutions.